# Android resource linking failed at google_play_service_version in generated menifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, proguard, android-bundle

When I set minifyEnabled true and build aar. its giving error 'android resource linking failed' at google_play_services_version in manifest while integrating it to the project.

I have added below code  to my aar manifest.

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and in proguard-rules.pro i have added

```
-keepnames class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}
```

And if i set minifyEnabled false than all works proper.

Can anyone help me out i am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue by keeping google_play_services_version values.xml file inside our main project.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the minifyEnabled true then defined the progurad rules for all third parties and other. Update each rule.

Comment: Hi I am using below three third parties 
1. implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
2.     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:18.0.1'
3.     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.1'

for all above three i have added 
-keepnames class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}

In progurad-. Anything missing apart from ?